# property's of 2 objects in a hash table into a new hash table

Tags: powershell, hashtable

Trying to get the property's of 2 objects in a hash table into a new hash table

```
$names.add = Foreach ($A in $grps.keys) {Get-DistributionGroupMember -
Identity '$A' | select name | Group-Object -Propertyname -AsHashTable}
```

i get the following error

```
The property 'add' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
At line:1 char:1
+ $names.add = Foreach ($A in $grps.keys) {Get-DistributionGroupMember -Identity ' ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: What is `$names`? How did you create it in the first place?

Comment: This is how names was created $names = @{}

Comment: `$names['add'] = foreach(...){...}`

Comment: Array index expression is missing or not valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$Grps = Get-DistributionGroupMember -Identity DG@company.com | select name | Group-Object -Property name -AsHashTable

$addr = $GRPS.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object {Get-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $_.name | select primarysmtpaddress| Group-Object -Property PRIMARYSMTPADDRESS -ashashtable }

Foreach ($A in $Addr.keys) {add-MailboxFolderPermission -id ${A}:\Calendar -user user@company.com -AccessRights limiteddetails}
```